# Using spark.shuffle.service.enabled property to start workers

Tags: apache-spark

As per the spark documentation documentation,

*

> There are two requirements for using this feature. First, your
>   application must set spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled to true. Second,
>   you must set up an external shuffle service on each worker node in the
>   same cluster and set spark.shuffle.service.enabled to true in your
>   application. The purpose of the external shuffle service is to allow
>   executors to be removed without deleting shuffle files written by them
>   (more detail described below). The way to set up this service varies
>   across cluster managers:
>
> **In standalone mode, simply start your workers
>   with spark.shuffle.service.enabled set to true.**

*

I am trying to start worker with below command

```
nohup ./spark-class --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://10.180.85.254:7077
```

This command is not starting the worker in background. Can anyone suggest the proper command?

Answer (score 0):

I have configured the property

```
spark.shuffle.service.enabled   true
```

inside `spark-defaults.conf` file for each worker.

This worked well.